# Override SenderBuilder class to add Bcc when sending invoice

Tags: magento2, event-observer, email, overrides, invoice

I didn't found an event when invoice email is sent, so i tried to override `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder` class, the override is working but getting the customer attribute `invoice_email` is not working, it works on my localhost by in the development website (which is multistore), it didn't work.
I don't know if there's a better solution to use an observer if there's a sending invoice email event

so in my module

**Vendor/ModuleName/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Sales\Order\Email\SenderBuilder" />
</config>
```

In **app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Model/Sales/Order/Email/SenderBuilder.php**

```
namespace Wetag\InvoiceEmail\Model\Sales\Order\Email;

class SenderBuilder extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder    
{



public function send()
{


    $this->configureEmailTemplate();

    $this->transportBuilder->addTo(
        $this->identityContainer->getCustomerEmail(),
        $this->identityContainer->getCustomerName()
    );

    $copyTo = $this->identityContainer->getEmailCopyTo();

    if (!empty($copyTo) && $this->identityContainer->getCopyMethod() == 'bcc') {
        foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
            $this->transportBuilder->addBcc($email);
        }
    }

    if($this->identityContainer  instanceof \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\InvoiceIdentity) {
    //do stuff

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $CustomerModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');

        $CustomerModel->setWebsiteId($this->identityContainer->getStore()->getStoreId()); 
        $CustomerModel->loadByEmail($this->identityContainer->getCustomerEmail());
        $email = $CustomerModel->getData()['invoice_email'];


        if(!empty($email)){

            $this->transportBuilder->addBcc($email);
        }

    }
    $transport = $this->transportBuilder->getTransport();
    $transport->sendMessage();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with the store id, it shouldn't to be get from the identityContainer, this is my solution

```
        $url = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $storeManager = $url->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

        $websiteId = $storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
        // Get Store ID
        //$store = $storeManager->getStore();
        //$storeId = $store->getStoreId();

        $CustomerModel->setWebsiteId($websiteId); 
        $CustomerModel->loadByEmail($this->identityContainer->getCustomerEmail());
        $email = $CustomerModel->getData()['invoice_email'];
```

Comment: Why you use object manager, like Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()? Don't do this.

Comment: @SohelRana how to do? i'm Magento beginner